# Play 2.4 value confDirectory is not a member of object play.PlayImport.PlayKeys

Tags: scala, sbt, upgrade, playframework-2.4

I'am trying to upgrade to play framework version 2.4 from version 2.3, but i have the following error:

```
value confDirectory is not a member of object play.PlayImport.PlayKeys
```

Besides,I add this import as play2.4 Migration guide mention but the error persisst

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport._
```

what is the correct import for the config directory?

Comment: Can you please share some parts of your `build.sbt` file, please?

Comment: this is the plugin.sbt:
 
```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.11")
```
for the build I am using scala file:
 
```
 import sbt._
 import Keys._
 import play.Play.autoImport._
 import play.PlayImport._
 import PlayKeys._
 import com.typesafe.sbt.less.Import.LessKeys
 import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport._

 lazy val appServerSettings = Seq(
 loggerConfig := confDirectory.value / "application-logger.xml")
```

Comment: this is what exist with play 2.3 , when change the play version and  refresh the sbt I got the error.

Comment: @Valy Dia
does it need a specific resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like the keys has been removed indeed. What if you use the `resourceDirectory` instead?

```scala
lazy val appServerSettings = Seq( 
  loggerConfig := resourceDirectory.value / "application-logger.xml",
  ...
)
```

In Play 2.7, this key does point toward the `conf` directory.

Comment: it works thanks a lot, could you please tell  How you get it because I did not understand, did you read the play 2.7 migration guide or what exactly?

Comment: Essentially, as it been removed from the `PlayKeys`, I just browse the `sbt` ones, and found it

Comment: I have also this import that I tried to resolve but I could not find the correctone: 
privateKeystore := (confDirectory in Compile).value / ").value / "test.private.jks"

Comment: when i used the resourceDirectory to import the key store value to the build file I got this error: 

** build/*:resourceDirectory from build/*:privateKeystore ((project.Build).scala:10)
[error]      Did you mean build/compile:resourceDirectory** 

pleas see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602527/play-framework2-4-can-not-add-key-store-value-to-scala-build-sbt-file