# Play framework2.4 can not add key store value to .scala build sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, upgrade, playframework-2.4

I'am trying to upgrade to play framework 2.4 from play 2.3, but when refreshing SBT I got the following error:

```
build/*:resourceDirectory from build/*:privateKeystore ((project.Build).scala:10)
[error]      Did you mean build/compile:resourceDirectory
```

I'am using .scala file as SBT build file

**play 2.3:** which used to be working well

```
 privateKeystore := confDirectory.value / "myProject.private.jks"
```

**play 2.4:** the change that caused the error

```
 privateKeystore := resourceDirectory.value / "myProject.private.jks"
```

note that confDirectory is not found for play2.4

Comment: Try changing this := resourceDirectory.value to := compile:resourceDirectory.value

Comment: @JonathanMyers, it did not work, it indicates syntax error, so may be it works with the play 2.4 syntax (if you have an idea about it). I tired also this but the build still running   for a lot of time: 
                    privateKeystore := (resourceDirectory in Compile value) / "myProject.private.jks"